# ¿Cómo hago para que un ciclo while me de los resultados que ingreso?

Tags: python, bucles, while

Necesito que este código me imprima el valor de todas las monedas con sus respectivas cantidades y cotizaciones.

```
def esmoneda(cripto):
    criptos = ["btc","bcc","ltc","eth","etc"]
    if cripto in criptos:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def esnumero(numero):
    return numero.replace('.','',1).isdigit()

i=0
while (i < 5):
    cripto=input("Ingrese el nombre de la moneda: ")
    if esmoneda(cripto):
        i=i+1
        cant = ""
        while not esnumero(cant):
            cant=input("Ingrese la cantidad de "+cripto+": ")
        cotiz = ""
        while not esnumero(cotiz):
            cotiz=input("Ingrese la cotización en USD de "+cripto+": ")
    else:
        print("Moneda invalida")

i=0
while i < 5:
    i=i+1
    print("Moneda: "+cripto+", Cantidad: "+cant+", Valor en USD: "+cotiz)
```

Esto como resultado me da el el último dato que ingreso *x5* de manera repetida.

Comment: Necesitas guardar tus datos en un array  y luego accederlos con tu ```while i<5```. Solo tienes una variable para cada dato  (```cripto```,```cant``` y ```cotiz```) y lo que haces es reescribirle encima a la variable cuando el usuario va a ingresar una nueva moneda. Con un array puedes guardar todos los datos por separado, en vez de solo tener un dato que pasas reescribiendo.

Answer (score 2):

Si no almacenas esos valores en una estructura apropiada (por ejemplo: una lista), entonces al final del primer `while` sólo tendrás almacenado en las variables la información referente al último elemento, porque por cada iteración que haga, irá sobreescribiendo los valores. Puedes utilizar por ejemplo:

```
resultado=[]
i=0
while (i < 5):
    cripto=input("Ingrese el nombre de la moneda: ")
    if esmoneda(cripto):
        i=i+1
        cant = ""
        while not esnumero(cant):
            cant=input("Ingrese la cantidad de "+cripto+": ")
        cotiz = ""
        while not esnumero(cotiz):
            cotiz = input("Ingrese la cotización en USD de " + cripto + ": ")
        resultado.append("Moneda: "+cripto+", Cantidad: "+cant+", Valor en USD: "+cotiz)
    else:
        print("Moneda invalida")

i=0
while i < 5:
    print(resultado[i])
    i = i + 1
```

PD: Los detalles agregados, se hicieron respetando tu código.

Answer (score 0):

gracias por los comentarios, quisiera compartirles mi propia solución basandome en las ayudas recibidas:

```
def esmoneda(cripto):
    criptos = ["btc","bcc","ltc","eth","etc"]
    if cripto in criptos:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def esnumero(numero):
    return numero.replace('.','',1).isdigit()

criptos = [] #Array vacio, luego se le agregan los datos del ciclo while.
cant = [] #Array vacio, luego se le agregan los datos del ciclo while.
cotiz = [] #Array vacio, luego se le agregan los datos del ciclo while.
i=0
while i < 5:
    criptoname = input("Ingrese el nombre de la moneda: ")
    if esmoneda(criptoname):
        criptos.append(criptoname) #el valor se agrega al array "criptos".
        criptocant = ""
        while not esnumero(criptocant):
            criptocant=input("Ingrese la cantidad de "+criptoname+": ")
        criptocotiz = ""
        while not esnumero(criptocotiz):
            criptocotiz=input("Ingrese la cotización en USD de "+criptoname+": ")
        cant.append(criptocant)
        cotiz.append(criptocotiz)
        i=i+1
    else:
        print("Moneda invalida")

i=0
while i < 5:
    print("Moneda: "+criptos[i]+", Cantidad: "+cant[i]+", Valor en USD: "+cotiz[i])
    i=i+1
```

Saludos!!